# How to find "title" of multi-dimensional array where value was found?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I'm trying to get the "title" of the nested array where the matched date was found...but to no avail.

If the date is found in the array, it should alert "TRUE". The date has to match or be within a date range. When It is found, I'd like to get the "Title" of the nested array where it was found to match. (IE. the date "10/29/2013" is found to match under "Person 2". I'd like to say that title as well.

I'm currently looping through both nested arrays to check for a match on the date. Eventually, they'll be a lot more people and times. To note, no time will show up twice within the array. This will be used to display who is available during that time on a webpage. While a database would be a much better route to go, this is sitting on a mainframe and will not be tied into DB2.

If there is an easier way of going about that, I'm all ears as well.

```
var data = []
var data = [
    {title:'Person 1',contents:[
        {primary:"7/09/2013"},{primary:"7/22/2013"},{primary:"10/15/2013"},{primary:"10/28/2013"},{primary:"1/21/2014"},{primary:"2/03/2014"}]},
    {title:'Person 2',contents:[
        {primary:"7/23/2013"},{primary:"8/05/2013"},{primary:"10/29/2013"},{primary:"11/11/2013"},{primary:"2/04/2014"},{primary:"2/17/2014"}]
    }
];

Array.prototype.between = function(arg) {
for(var i=0, j=data.length; i < j; i++){
    for(var p=0, plen=data[i].contents.length; p < plen; p++){
        var d1 = new Date(data[i].contents[0].primary),
            d2 = new Date(data[i].contents[1].primary),
            d4 = new Date(data[i].contents[2].primary),
            d5 = new Date(data[i].contents[3].primary),
            d3 = new Date(arg);
        }
        //alert(data[i].title); //Using "data[i].title" will grab both titles but I only need one.
    }
return ((d1.getTime() <= d3.getTime() && d3.getTime() <= d2.getTime()) || (d4.getTime() <= d3.getTime() && d3.getTime() <= d5.getTime()));
}

alert(data.between("10/29/2013"));
```

And the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/sherman2k2/E3ASy/1/

Comment: if you made the dates an array instead of repeated-key objects it would be simpler to code your logic.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me. Each time through that inner loop, you reset the values of all those "d" variables.  At the end of the function, the values will be those from the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your code should look something like this:

```
Array.prototype.between = function(arg) {
    for(var i=0, j=data.length; i < j; i++){
        for(var p=0, plen=data[i].contents.length; p < plen; p++){
            var d1 = new Date(data[i].contents[0].primary),
                d2 = new Date(data[i].contents[1].primary),
                d4 = new Date(data[i].contents[2].primary),
                d5 = new Date(data[i].contents[3].primary),
                d3 = new Date(arg);
            if ((d1.getTime() <= d3.getTime() && d3.getTime() <= d2.getTime()) || (d4.getTime() <= d3.getTime() && d3.getTime() <= d5.getTime()))
                return data[i].title;
        }
    }
}
```

When you call the function, it'll return either the title or else `undefined` if the date doesn't match.

Comment: That's basically what I was looking for. I'm sure my code wasn't in the best format but I had been using several versions of it and began to get a bit lost within the code. This helps set me back on path.